# Biometric/ Graphometric Signature Android

Tags: android, signature, biometrics

Are there any libraries or API about Graphometric Signature for Android? I need to integrate to my Android app a (biometric) graphometric signature system. Grafometric sisgnature is only valid legal signature.

Answer (score 1):

you can try Namirial S.p.A. solution.

http://www.graphosign.com/

http://www.firmagrafometrica.it/

You can use the Namirial solution with Windows, Android & iOs.

They also provide an sdk for the all platform.

For more information you can send an email to: info@graphosign.com